# Django fails when saving a serializer with foreign key references

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So I had a model with one foreign key reference that was working really well for a few weeks. I ended up having to add another foreign key reference to the model and now I'm not able to save any records using a serializer. I should mention I'm using Django 2.1.
Here's the model I'm using (some fields removed for simplicity):

```html
class Finding(models.Model):
    finding_id = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    web_app = models.ForeignKey(WebApplication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    q_id = models.ForeignKey(StagingQkb, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The new FK is the q_id field. This was just a plain int before. I've actually blown away the old table and the new one is still totally empty so I know it's not a problem with the existing data (the tables with the foreign keys are still intact). When saving Findings before, I would just give the PK of the WebApplication object for 'web_app'. As far as I can tell this is still working. The 'q_id' field, when inserted the same way, complains that it needs an int/string/bytes instead of a StagingQkb object. Well, I'm not giving it a StagingQkb object so what gives!

Here's the serializer:

```html
class FindingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Finding
        fields = '__all__'
```

The data I'm feeding to the serializer looks like this:

```html
data = {'finding_id': 5514989,
        'name': 'Sample-Name',
        'q_id': 12345,
        'web_app': 67890}
```

When I insert the data into the serializer I'm doing the following:

```html
>>> fs = FindingSerializer(data=data)
>>> fs.is_valid()
True
>>> fs.save()
```

The error I'm getting after running the above code looks like this:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 959, in create
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `Finding.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Finding.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the FindingSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception was:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 940, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 413, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/dpz3w0q/AutonomousPrimeD/autonomousprimed/Finding/models.py", line 83, in save
    q_id=self.q_id)
  File "/home/dpz3w0q/AutonomousPrimeD/autonomousprimed/Finding/models.py", line 173, in evaluate
    if ScoreMatrix.objects.filter(q_id=q_id).count() > 0:
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1096, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 70, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/opt/oss/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1807, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'StagingQkb'
```

I'm completely stuck here. I haven't changed the way I'm passing data to the serializer, so I really can't tell what I've done wrong. If anyone is able to help me work through this I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: The traceback seems to indicate that some additional code is being run in `models.py` - possibly called from `Finding.save()`. Are you able to show all the code from `models.py`?

Comment: Hi Will, thanks, that's a good point! The save method looks like this:
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    if self.web_app.sys_id is not None and self.web_app.sys_id.composite_dav is not None and \
            self.q_type is not 'INFORMATION_GATHERED':
        self.rating = ScoreMatrix.evaluate(dav=self.web_app.sys_id.composite_dav, severity=self.severity,
                                              q_id=self.q_id)
    else:
        self.rating = None
    super().save()

Comment: I'll try changing the reference to self.q_id to refer to the PK of the foreign table and report back once I know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @WillKeeling I realized that I had a reference to Finding.q_id in my save() method that I forgot to update after making the FK changes. The PK of the foreign table is qkb_id, so I changed the reference to Finding.q_id.qkb_id and I was able to save the model.